# How to move files in python?

Tags: python, file

When I try moving files with shutil, only three of the files are moved, then nothing else. Can someone explain what is happening and how to fix it?

I'm using a dataset to identify the proper image and put it in a folder name the individual_id. The index is just a string of the image name.

```
test = train_df.groupby('image').sum()
```

output of test.head(4):

| image(index) | species | individual_id | class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00021adfb725ed.jpg | melon_headed_whale | cadddb1636b9 | whale |
| 000562241d384d.jpg | humpback_whale | 1a71fbb72250 | whale |
| 0007c33415ce37.jpg | false_killer_whale | 60008f293a2 | whale |
| 0007d9bca26a99.jpg | bottlenose_dolphin | 4b00fe572063 | dolphin |

And here is the code for moving the files:

```
images = os.listdir('images/train_images/')

for image in images:
    for idx, id in enumerate(test):
        if image == test.index[idx]:
            shutil.move(src=f'images/train_images/{image}', dst=f'images/categories/{test.values[idx][1]}', copy_function=copy2)
```

EDIT: The table shows up in preview, but not my post.

Comment: @kenntnisse I'm not sure what is happening with the table. It shows up in the preview, but not the post

Comment: Have you tried printing the src and dest actually passed to move?  Please read the help on how to ask a question.  You should provide a small, runnable program that people can try, which shows the problem you're trying to solve. Guessing from partial code is not fun and often not successful.